# Wordpress plugin, database not creating

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I am trying to create a database within a Wordpress plugin. The database will be to hold information about packages that can be made within this plugin.

Here is my code to create the table:

```
function create_wispabb_table() {
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wispabb_packages";
//create table
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$table_name` (
   `package_id` int(15) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `name` varchar(250) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `description` text collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `backup_capacity` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `briefcase_capacity` int(10) NOT NULL,
   `upload_speed` int(10) NOT NULL,
   `monthly_price` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`package_id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;";
  $wpdb->query($query);
}
```

When I try to call the database to display packages or add a new package I get the following error. WordPress database error: [Table 'wordpress.wp_wispabb_packages' doesn't exist]

I'm not sure what I'm missing, and any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: you can simple use   mysql_query('your query') for this

Comment: Use `echo` before `executing` the `query`, and then run the `query` in `phpmyadmin` or `mysql`. Also you are not creating `database` you are just creating a `table`. Right?

Comment: yes sorry its to add a table within the database. My mistake. where do i put echo? before $query?

Comment: Yes before **$query** or try this **die($query);**

Comment: neither works still not sure what i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your page,

```
 add_action('init','create_wispabb_table');
```

**Or**

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'create_wispabb_table');
```

Comment: when i refreshed it after adding that line all i get is

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_wispabb_packages` ( `package_id` int(15) NOT NULL auto_increment, `name` varchar(250) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, `description` text collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, `backup_capacity` int(10) NOT NULL, `briefcase_capacity` int(10) NOT NULL, `upload_speed` int(10) NOT NULL, `monthly_price` float(10,2) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`package_id`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

Comment: Run this `query` in `mysql` or in `phpmyadmin`

Comment: i need the plugin to create the table

Comment: @user1937185 test the above I have made changes in it.

Comment: It already has 
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'create_wispabb_table');

when I add the  add_action('init','create_wispabb_table');

it does what I said in the previous comment, just shows the query

Comment: ok this seems to be fixed but now when i try add data it gives me an internal server error. thank you for all the help